# Entity Framework - Linq - Comparing Nullable objects - NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I need to compare an object with a parameter that I'm passing in. The logic being:

- If `territory == null`. Return all `Orders`
- If `territory != null` and the `Territory` entity from Orders is `!= null`. Return `Orders` matching on the `Id` property (PK) of both entities.

I have the following LINQ statement:

The cut down version of my method is (there are normally other filters in the `WHERE` clause):

```
  public void Execute(Territory territory)
  {
    using (var context = DatabaseHelper.CreateContext())
    {
      var orders = context.Orders.Where(x =>
        (
          (territory == null) ||
          (x.Territory != null && x.Territory.Id == territory.Id)
          )
        );

      if (!orders.Any()) //Exception occurs here on materialising the query
      {
        //Do something
      }
    }
  }
```

I receive the exception `NotSupportedException` and the message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'ENTITY'. Only primitive types or
>   enumeration types are supported in this context.

Whilst I understand the error as I'm not passing in a primitive type. How can I change the LINQ query so it returns the expected results?

Comment: Is this truly all of the code in your method, or is there anything you're omitting beyond the end tag for the 'using' statement?

Comment: Also, please paste the code for the 'DatabaseHelper.CreateContext' method.

Comment: Edited the code in my question. However, no, it is only upon the query being executed that I receive the error on the line after. The CreateContext method just returns an inststance of DbContext with a given name for the connection string.

Comment: @Hopeless Only because they don't relate to the issue. Without them included in the Where I still receive the same issue.

Comment: I understand, but if you're returning a generic context, not strongly typed, then you are using a generic context, which would not throw an exception upon querying, not in the 'using' statement which is executing your method.

Comment: @JBond I've not read your query carefully

Comment: @JustinRusso I see what you mean. Yes technically it returns a class 'CoreContext' that inherits from DbContext. It is that context that I use throughout.

Comment: @JBond, that could be a potential problem.  Is there any reason why you cannot use EF to create a context, and just use that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var t = territory == null;
var orders = context.Orders.Where(x =>        
       t || (x.Territory != null && x.Territory.Id == territory.Id));
```

The reason behind this is it tries to translate `territory` into a constant in SQL query but of course `territory` is not primitive or any equivalent type on server, so it throws the exception. You can however cache a constant boolean outside (but still in the effective scope of checking `territory`) and use that constant in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to filter by territory.id only if territory is not null. This will also result in shorter sql query being generated.

```
var orders = context.Orders;

if (territory != null)
{
    orders = orders.Where(x.Territory != null && x.Territory.Id == territory.Id)
}
```